# TypeScript: How to add an absolute path to the root directory to import files from there?

Tags: typescript, directory, absolute-path, tsconfig

I have my TS config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "jest.config.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".next", "out", "build", "coverage"]
```

And want to reference a TS file in the root directory for one of my components so it is cleaner:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withTranslation, Link } from '../../../i18n';

const Header = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
      <Flex>
        <Box>
          <Link href="/">HOME</Link>
        </Box>
      </Flex>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

How do I update the `tsconfig` to reference the i18n absolutely?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `i18n` folder is in the root, you can use the `paths` property in the `tsconfig`.

[More info here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
       "i18n": ["i18n"]
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "jest.config.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".next", "out", "build", "coverage"]
}
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withTranslation, Link } from 'i18n';

const Header = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
      <Flex>
        <Box>
          <Link href="/">HOME</Link>
        </Box>
      </Flex>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```